# What version of PHP allows type hints to override typeless identifiers?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, types, type-hinting

When I try to override a typeless identifier, it works fine in my interactive shell (PHP 5.6):

```
php -a
Interactive shell

php > class A { public function me($me) { var_dump($me); } }
php > class B extends A { public function me(\One $me) { parent::me($me); } }
php > class One { } // Yes, somehow this was legal.
php > $a = new A();
php > $a->me('hi');
string(2) "hi"
php > $b = new B();
php > $b->me(new One());
object(One)#3 (0) {
}
php > $b->me('hi');
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to B::me() must be an instance of One, string given, called in php shell code on line 1 and defined in php shell code on line 1

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to B::me() must be an instance of One, string given, called in php shell code on line 1 and defined in php shell code on line 1
```

But on my 5.3 server, it gives me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of B::me() must be compatible with that of A::me() in B.php on line 20
```

I could not find any information on this discrepancy from Google or the PHP docs.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: I already said that I read the entire page. Actually, now I have it open twice since I clicked your link. Maybe I'm misunderstanding a sentence on that page, but I could not find where it addresses my issue.

Comment: That's for the `callable` keyword. Nowhere in my example am I using the callable keyword.